# DNS propagation taking over two months

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain, nameserver, domain-registration

Two months ago I registered bunch of expired domains and set new nameservers to them just like I've done before. Never had any issues.

For some reason the DNS propagation never finished with these domains. When I use any DNS propagation checker, they show that some of the servers are pointing to the correct IP, but many are still pointing to the old ones. And they keep switching between the new and old ones.

One example is domain.ax. If you go to whois.ax (the official .ax registry site) to check the domain, it tells that the nameservers are correct, hostgator.com ones.
But when checking with tools like intodns.com, they find more nameservers. In this case parkingcrew.net nameservers, which were set by the previous owner of the domain.
And again, DNS propagation checkers find up to four different IPs, at the moment correct should be the one ending .188.

Any suggestions what could be wrong here? My knowledge about this stuff is very limited.

Comment: There is no DNS propagation, this is a myth. What counts are TTLs. You need to query authoritative nameservers first at parent and then go down to see records and their TTLs. Updates should show there immediately after the nameserver is loaded with new data then you test recursive ones. You should have given one of your domains that has problems (not sure if domain.ax is really yours). What appears in the whois has no operational consequences. Online checking tools like https://dnsviz.net/d/domain.ax/dnssec/ will show you are in a lame delegation case, mismatch in NS RRset from parent to child

Answer (score 3):

Either your registrar or you misconfigured the `NS` records. `ns1.aland.net` is one of `.ax` authoritative nameservers:

```
piotr@bialykiel:~$ dig @ns1.aland.net domain.ax NS
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
domain.ax.      86400   IN  NS  cns2076.hostgator.com.
domain.ax.      86400   IN  NS  cns2075.hostgator.com.
domain.ax.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.parkingcrew.net.
```

There is a third DNS server configured on your TLD servers. Usually you can configure them in some panel on your registrar's website.

Comment: You've beaten me by narrow margin.

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for your reply. I went and updated the nameservers. I added the nameservers of my other hostgator hosting service too just to test. So there should be four hostgator.com now. 
Not sure if this is too early since I don't know how (fast) these things update. But when I do these checks, mxtoolbox.com for example, all four of my nameservers are there, but the parkingcrew is also there. That is something I haven't set, and it's not visible to me anywhere in the panels. Everything else is empty. Should I already be worried about that?

Comment: If you just deleted that nameserver give them some time. If it didn't show up in the panel before, report the problem to your DNS provider.

Comment: mxtoolbox are querying your name servers at hostgator and I am concerned that they are currently responding with different results. Hostgator should very quickly converge to give the same results to a direct query. Check what the hostgator control panel is showing.

Comment: The new servers are there but the old one (ns1.parkingcrew.net) still remains. I would say that if you don't see it in your panel then ask your registrar for help. It also doesn't show in whois data so there is something fishy here.